# Script for copying a folder somewhere using Git Bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I want to copy a folder `~/Projects/LocalProject` onto my server `//VM-Server/ServerProject`.

I know that I can use GitBash:

`cp -r directory-name-1 directory-name-2`

But what I'm curious about is, can I create a script to do that by double clicking that script, or adding it as a command to my GitBash, cause I will need that alot?

--Edit--

Tried nothing, as I don't know how to do that. Yes there are hidden files, I don't want them to be copied. There shouldn't be newer files on the destination. I need to manually run it, I thought that's clear as I mentioned the option to have a executable script / or a terminal command.

Comment: Yes. So what have you tried? Is this just moving one folder to another on the same machine? Are there hidden files? What if a file in the destination is newer? Could it run on a schedule, or at login? Please add more info.

Comment: Tried nothing, as I don't know how to do that. Yes there are hidden files, I don't want them to be copied. There shouldn't be newer files on the destination. I need to manually run it, I thought that's clear as I mentioned the option to have a executable script / or a terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Batch file

You don't even need git-bash; you can make a batch file in any text editor, name it `copy to server.bat`, and type in `cp C:\Users\<Your username>\Projects\LocalProject \\VM-Server\ServerProject`.

You can also make a `.sh` file for use in bash. The command is the same, just make note that Windows uses `\`, while bash uses `/` for directory tree

#### Option 2: Alias

Open your `bash_profile` file (it's in your git bash install location).
Add a line at the end of the file that says `alias copyToServer = 'cp ~/Projects/LocalProject //VM-Server/ServerProject'`. Then close git-bash, reopen it and use the command by typing `copyToServer` as a bash command. (It doesn't need to be named `copyToServer`)

Comment: bash_profile.sh? I added it there, but that did not work. 
A command would be awesome :)

Comment: You have to close and reopen git-bash for new aliases to work

Comment: still does not work :/

Comment: Then try with `%LocalAppData%\Programs\Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh`

Comment: I tried that, but does not work either.

It tells me when launching the gitbash:

bash: alias: copyServercp -r ~/Projects/LocalProject/. //VM-Server/ServerProject/

case "$TERM" in
xterm*)
        # The following programs are known to require a Win32 Console
        # for interactive usage, therefore lets: not found
bash: alias: launch: not found
bash: alias: them: not found
bash: alias: through: not found
bash: alias: winpty: not found
bash: /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
bash: /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh: line 21: `     ;;'

Comment: Try with `C:\Git\etc\profile.d\git-prompt.sh`